# Mac make nachos with some problems

Tags: macos, nachos

I want to compile nachos resource, but some problems happened when I run 'make depend':

[image]

What does it mean?  How to fix?

Comment: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/system_error:285:43: error:
      use of undeclared identifier '***'

Comment: Please don't put part of your question in the comments area. Instead, click `edit` under your question and the question it so it accurately shows all the necessary information.